# make search result linkable?

Tags: php, search, hyperlink

I have made this little search script that locates users and am trying to make the search results clickable. i am trying to point the url to the profile id but not having much luck. basically each profile has an id of 1,2, 3, 4 etc and i need to find a way of making the search result correspond with the profile id when clicked. can anyone help please?

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="text" name="query" class="search" placeholder="Search Name/Location" style="width:120px;"/>
<input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" class="searchbutton" name="submit" value="Start Search" />
</form>

<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="database";
$db_tb_name="ptb_profiles";
$db_tb_atr_name="display_name";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$db_tb_name` 
        WHERE display_name like '%".$query."%' 
        OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR orientation LIKE '%".$query."%'");
echo "<div class=\"results\">";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<div class=\"spacing\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$profile['user_id']}\">";
    echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</a></div>";

}


mysql_close();
}

?>
```

I was trying to use this function but it just lists the all the users and basically isnt what i want.

```
function get_searched_users() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
                        WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"user\"
                        AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
                        AND display_name like '%".$query."%' 
        OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR age LIKE '%".$query."%'";
            $search_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($search_set);
            return $search_set;

    }
```

Comment: `{$profile['user_id']}` - Shouldn't that be `{$data_fetch['user_id']}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<div class=\"spacing\">";
    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$data_fetch['user_id']}\">";
    echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</a></div>";
}
```

Effectively you need to use the `$data_fetch` variable and you were using the `$profile` one.